# How would I go about turning english sentences into predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am taking a Discrete Mathematics for Computer Science course and was having some issues figuring this out. I would rather not be given a specific answer, but the steps on how I could solve this. If you happen to have another example that would be great!

The equation $x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$ has no solutions over the natural numbers.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a statement expressed in natural language into mathematical language, you have to transform it using a series of steps, at every step only perform a transformation that makes the statement more concise. (obviously ensuring to keep the exact same meaning step after step) 
Example:

1. The equation $x^2+2x+1=0$ has no solutions over the natural numbers.
2. The equation $x^2+2x+1=0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{N}$.
3. no $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$ is a solution of $ x^2+2x+1 = 0$
4. if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then $ x^2+2x+1 \neq 0$
5. $(\forall x \in \mathbb{N})(x^2+2x+1 \neq 0)$

another example: $U$ (stack exchange humans set), $E$ (english speaking umans)

1. (it is false to say that) (no one among us can talk english well.)
2. $\lnot (\ (\forall p \in U)( p \notin E)\ )$
3. $(\exists  p \in U)(p \in E)$
4. $U \cap E \neq \phi$

so in the first step i turned the "it is false to say that" into a $\lnot$ and i used sets and quantifiers to transform the rest
then it's just algebra.

Comment: Chose this as the answer because it explained how the answer was achieved, with steps. Thank you. This allowed me to understand how to do other problems as well!!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working in a first order language of arithmetic. The desired sentence would be

$$(\forall x)(x^2 + 2x + 1 \neq 0)$$

In your intended model of of arithmetic $\mathbb{N}$, you would have the the above is true in $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are no values $x$ such that $x \in \mathbb N$ and such that $x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$...

This readily translates into the following translation: $$\lnot \exists x\big((x \in \mathbb N) \land (x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0)\big)$$

Alternatively, we can write $$\forall x\big(x \in \mathbb N \rightarrow x^2 + 2x + 1 \neq 0\big)$$

You can check for yourself that the two statements are equivalent.